# Find an orthogonal matrix such that its first line is $\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

An orthogonal matrix is one matrix $A$ such that $A^t = A^{-1}$. So what I did:

Suppose:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{5}&\frac{2}{5}\\x&y\end{bmatrix}$$

Then:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{5}&\frac{2}{5}\\x&y\end{bmatrix}^T = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{5}&\frac{2}{5}\\x&y\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$

This input on wolfram alpha gives [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=transpose%20of%20%7B%7B1%2F5%2C2%2F5%7D%2C%7Bx%2Cy%7D%7D%20%3D%20inverse%20of%20%7B%7B1%2F5%2C2%2F5%7D%2C%7Bx%2Cy%7D%7D&dataset=) which gives [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F5%3Dy%2F%28y%2F5-%282%20x%29%2F5%29%3Bx%3D-%282%2F%285%20%28y%2F5-%282%20x%29%2F5%29%29%29%3B2%2F5%3D-%28x%2F%28y%2F5-%282%20x%29%2F5%29%29%3By%3D1%2F%285%20%28y%2F5-%282%20x%29%2F5%29%29) system. But this is not the answer in my book. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's impossible: an orthogonal matrix has orthonormal vectors and rows, so each of their norms should be 1, but the first row has a magnitude of $\sqrt{5/25}$

Comment: Yeah I too feel like there is something missing to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: Use $A^{T}A = AA^{T} = I_2$ to get a system of linear equations to solve for the variables $x,y$.

Comment: but what's wrong with my definition?

Comment: nothing wrong with it, you just use my hint to continue to the answer.

Comment: but I've got a system from the definition, but it has no solutions. Whats happening?